# Ruby MYSQL conditional statement

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a ruby script which queries the database, extracts some info and publishes the result. The ***row*** in the code snippet below is a record(I'm looping through the rows). I have a flag *Cancelled* [Which is of datatype bit(1)] in the table.
Irrespective of the flag value, I am always publishing Cancelled = 'No'. Basically the conditional statement is always returning false even though that's not the case. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new(parameters....)
query_str = "Some query"
row = db.query(query_str).first        

Cancelled = 'No'
if row['Cancelled'] == true
  Cancelled = 'Yes'
end
```

Comment: Have you looked at what `row['Cancelled']` is when the bit is set? There's no reason to assume that it will be `true`, I'd guess that it is a byte with a single bit set.

Comment: The Column 'Cancelled' is of type bit(1). It can't be a byte, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: But it won't be a single bit when it hits Ruby and I doubt it will be `true` or `false` either. So look at it and see what it really is. I would guess that `bit(n)` will end up being a bitmap that is zero-padded to fill bytes (which is probably how it is stored inside MySQL too).

Comment: I didn't know that...Thank you...I did a _cast_booleans => true_. Worked like a charm.